# Is there a workaround to ensure Index Only Scan on jsondoc->>'....' equality queries?

Tags: postgresql

I architected an entire application around the idea of storing unprocessed JSON documents in `jsonb` and then selectively creating covering indexes using field access expressions of the form `(jsondoc->>'fieldname')` to ensure all required queries can execute as *Index Only Scans*. The idea of storing the raw json is very attractive because it removes an entire ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) layer which has been a constant source of bugs and operational headaches.

The pgsql manual contains this very unfortunate fact:

> In principle, index-only scans can be used with expression indexes.
>   For example, given an index on f(x) where x is a table column, it
>   should be possible to execute

```
SELECT f(x) FROM tab WHERE f(x) < 1;
```

> as an index-only scan; and this is very attractive if f() is an
>   expensive-to-compute function. **However, PostgreSQL's planner is
>   currently not very smart about such cases.** It considers a query to be
>   potentially executable by index-only scan only when all columns needed
>   by the query are available from the index. In this example, x is not
>   needed except in the context f(x), but the planner does not notice
>   that and concludes that an index-only scan is not possible. If an
>   index-only scan seems sufficiently worthwhile, this can be worked
>   around by declaring the index to be on (f(x), x), where the second
>   column is not expected to be used in practice but is just there to
>   convince the planner that an index-only scan is possible. An
>   additional caveat, if the goal is to avoid recalculating f(x), is that
>   the planner won't necessarily match uses of f(x) that aren't in
>   indexable WHERE clauses to the index column. It will usually get this
>   right in simple queries such as shown above, but not in queries that
>   involve joins. These deficiencies may be remedied in future versions
>   of PostgreSQL.

**My question is very specifically:**

How can the workaround described for 'x' be applied to `jsonb` columns, without replicating the enormous json payload in the index?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. This is a good example why it is better to use a regular relational schema than JSON. One workaround is to store the individual fields in addition to the whole JSON if you really need the latter.

Comment: I think designing a database "*to ensure all required queries can execute as Index Only Scans*" is a bad starting point to begin with. You should first come up with a good solid database design, then design your queries, then design your indexing strategy around those queries. An index only scan is not always guaranteed to be the most efficient strategy for the planner. Creating indexes for each and every single attribute you want to retrieve is a massive "overkill". I also agree with Laurenz: you should first try a proper normalized relational approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the fields you want index-only scans on into [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) and create the corresponding covering indexes on the generated columns. The query planner can then use an index-only scan.

Assuming that you only need to do this for a few fields, it should be much more efficient than an index that includes the full `jsondoc` column.